# Could I add to an existing join table model, in a many to many relationship?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, migration

I have a standard relationship:

```
class User <ActiveRecord:: Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many: feeds,: uniq => true
end

class Feed <ActiveRecord:: Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many: users,: uniq => true
end
```

And according to the rails naming convention, the join table is called
'users_feeds'.

I need to extend the functionality of join table, and add the model UserFeed (or UsersFeeds ?).

1. Does adding the model is a disorder of the rails convention?
2. Do I need to change the name of the join table, and define a relationship using the option :through?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Adding a class for your join model is fine.  You should not need to change the table name.  The resulting code will look something like:

```
class User <ActiveRecord:: Base
  has_many :user_feeds
  has_many :feeds, :through=>:user_feeds
end

class UserFeed <ActiveRecord:: Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :feed
end

class Feed <ActiveRecord:: Base
  has_many :user_feeds
  has_and_belongs_to_many: users, :through=>:user_feeds
end
```